# Breaking String variable to multiple lines Android

Tags: java, string, line-breaks

I have a variable called Address. `String address=36c,Bandaranayaka Road,Colombo07` 
Actually what i want is to, print the variable content in multiple lines.

Ex:

```
36c,
Bandaranayaka Road,
Colombo07
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subString()` method

that will help you.